# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

> [What is the purpose of the 6th Precept, eating only before noon?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13693/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-6th-precept-eating-only-before-noon)

I know the title is similar to a [previous question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/what-is-the-purpose-of-not-eating-after-noon) but this one consists of three inter related questions which were not covered by the original. The answer is much more comprehensive and I do not want it to be lost. I think editing the title would have been better than branding it as a duplicate.

Comment: The titles suggest it's an exact duplicate. Would a better title be something like, "Can one vary (alter) the 6th precept, to accommodate one's family?"

Comment: @ChrisW yeah that sounds good.  What about, 'Can one alter the 6th precept to accommodate one's family or daily routines?'

Comment: Make that edit to the title then, and maybe Andrei would reopen it. In either case the question and upvoted answer won't be auto-deleted (the question's being closed merely prevents any further answers). Also, speaking of edits, the question body starts, "Firstly, what is the purpose of it". A better question might start, "Firstly, I've read [What is the purpose of not eating after noon?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/what-is-the-purpose-of-not-eating-after-noon) and [I don't have any questions about that] or [I still have a question about that, which is, XXX]."

Comment: Oh, very good teamwork!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the edit. I reopened it.

Comment: I am still editing it. I think the original is on monks' perspective but this one is on laity's angle. I was trying to incorporate this difference in the question. Would you mind if I do that?

Comment: If you can make the question more interesting or clearer then so much the better, especially if you preserve the OP's intent, and don't invalidate (i.e. render irrelevant or obsolete) the existing answer.

Comment: Thanks. Edited. Does it look clear now?